# XSLT to output multiple XML Files in a single pass

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file:

```
<root>
  <Person ID="123">
    <Name @name="JohnDoe"/>
    <OtherInfo>
      ......
    </OtherInfo>
  </Person>

  <Person ID="456">
    <Name @name="JaneDoe"/>
    <OtherInfo>
      ......
    </OtherInfo>
  </Person>

  <Person ID="789">
    <Name @name="JohnDoe"/>
    <OtherInfo>
      ......
    </OtherInfo>
  </Person>
</root>
```

I want a single XSLT file to output two files:

File1:

```
<root>
  <Person ID="123">
    <OtherInfo>
      ......
    </OtherInfo>
  </Person>

  <Person ID="456">
    <OtherInfo>
      ......
    </OtherInfo>
  </Person>

  <Person ID="789">
    <OtherInfo>
      ......
    </OtherInfo>
  </Person>
</root>
```

File2:
JohnDoe, JaneDoe, JohnDoe

I want to be able to do this in a single pass through the original XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easily done in XSLT 2.0 using the `xsl:result-document` instruction.

It's not possible in XSLT 1.0 unless your 1.0 processor has a proprietary extension equivalent to `xsl:result-document`.

Comment: In XSLT 2.0, would is just be something along the lines of 

<xsl:result-document>

Comment: You can find some examples and explanation at http://etutorials.org/XML/xml+hacks/Chapter+3.+Transforming+XML+Documents/Hack+45+Generate+Multiple+Output+Documents+with+XSLT+2.0/